# selectall() property in C# for textbox control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know, there is a property for textbox control in windows form, called `selectall()`.

I am trying to achieve the same in my web app, for a textbox, once it recieves the `focus()`, i am trying to select all the text in the textbox.

I know I can write some jquery for this, but, is there any other easier way to achieve this?

Comment: Other easy way... are you fooling us

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" onFocus="this.select()" />
```

Comment: Thanks Guys, i guess, i will go with using jQuery.

Answer (score 12):

No, you cannot do this without some client side scripting code. The code is very simple, though. In your `Page_Load` event, just specify:

```
myTextBox.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "this.select()")
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, I have used this and it works great - does it depend on jQuery for the ".select()" method call?

Comment: @condiosluzverde: No, [it's plain JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select).

Answer (score 1):

```
Textbox1.Attributes["onFocus"] = "this.select()";
```